# the random heights of north american women

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

**The heights of North American women are normally distributed with a mean of 64 inches and a standard deviation of 2 inches.
A random sample of four women is selected. What is the probability that the sample mean height is greater than 66 inches?**

What is the formula for going about this problem? I am searching through my textbook, but cant seem to find out how to solve this. The random sample of four is the part that is throwing me off.

Comment: If x has a normal distribution, what can we say about the distribution of $\bar{x}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Say that your four sampled heights are $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$. These are independent random variables that are normally distributed with mean $64$ and standard deviation $2$.

The question is then asking you for
$$
P\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4}{4}\geq66\right).
$$

Comment: I tried 66 divided by four using the logic above, but it is asking for a decimal answer to four places. I plugged it into a normal distribution function on excel but that is not working either.